# Drop-Down Image List

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to find a dropdown-style list for images I can use in a program of mine. It just needs to display a few images in a grid with tooltips for each one, and I need to be able to get whichever one was last picked. For example *(without the tab bar in it)*:

[image]

Unfortunately my monetary budget is zero which means I can't purchase any controls. Are there any free ones like this, or will I need to work at making my own?

If the answer is the latter, are there any useful links you might be able to give me so I could start to work on a control for this?

Comment: offtopic: using wpf instead will ease the problem greatly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inherit your class from `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox` and override the protected method `OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)`

**Example code:**

```
public class ImageComboBox : ComboBox
{
   protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
   {
      // Get the item.
      var item = this.Items[e.Index] as string;
      if(item == null)
         return;

      // Get the coordinates to where to draw the image.
      int imageX = e.Bounds.X + 5;
      int imageY = (e.Bounds.Height - image.Height) / 2;

      // Draw image
      e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, new Point(imageX, imageY));

      // Draw text
      e.Graphics.DrawString(item, this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
            new PointF(textX, textY);
   }
}
```

The code above is only a quick and dirty example, and should not be used as it is (should not for example create a new SolidBrush each time the item is drawn), but I hope it will give you an idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots implementations of custom image drop-down lists out there.

You should take a look at the [`DrawMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode.aspx) property of the `ComboBox`.

Here's a simple example that implements the use of an `ImageList`, by inheriting from `ComboBox`, setting the `DrawMode` to `OwnerDrawFixed` and drawing its elements in `OnDrawItem`:

[`ComboBox` With Images](http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/combobox-with-images/)

I'm not sure if this approach enables you to implement the grid-style image list that you mention, but take a look at the example - I'm sure it fits your needs just fine.