# line color, line style, line weight combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

What kind of controls should I use to develop a screen like this
Picture box? combobox with line styles?

[image: line style selection dialog]

Comment: Controls? Like a drop down box? Your question is not clear.

Comment: I dont see any color picker, line style, line weight controls in C# tool box.How would I get a line style picker in the combo box.

Comment: This will be a breeze in WPF, a bit more complicated in WinForms. Which are you using?

Comment: @ Avner Shahar-Kashtan, @user1415038: C# winforms

Comment: In that case, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1286248/drop-down-image-list-in-winforms, which has answers on how to manually draw your own combobox items.

Comment: @Avner Shahar-Kashtan: In the link u recommended: To override the OnDrawItem, the class must inherit from System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox. So in my windows form, I am already inherting from  public partial class frmDlgGraphOptions : Form, ComboBox
    {
        public frmDlgGraphOptions()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }. So will this be enough to override the DrawItemEvent

Comment: I have the same exact question. Binding these is also something that I wish I could find some info on.

Answer (score -1):

```
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="5" Width="80" Height="4" StrokeDashArray="4 1 1 3" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="2"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="5" Width="80" Height="4" StrokeDashArray="4 3" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="2"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="5" Width="80" Height="4" StrokeDashArray="4 6" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="2"></Rectangle>
        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Margin="5" Width="80"  Height="4" StrokeDashArray="4 8" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashOffset="2"></Rectangle>


    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: You should edit your answer to include details and explanations for how this code answers the question.

Comment: Eres muy corto... que eres de la LOGSE?